# What is meant by an HTML5 application?

Tags: terminology, html5

Since HTML5 is still only a markup language, what is meant when people say "HTML5 application"? Please explain.

Comment: You may want to mention where you got your current definition and what specifically you need clarification. Otherwise, this may get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HTML5 application is an application that uses HTML5/Javascript/CSS3 as its primary means of achieving a User Interface.

The term is significant, largely because this is considered a platform-independent way to get an application onto as many different mobile devices as possible.  Android and iOS are pretty much completely different, but both platforms will work with applications written in HTML5/Javascript/CSS3.  All you need is an HTML5 compliant browser.

Comment: With Javascript handling actual functionality, and HTML/CSS used purely for graphic design. Right?

Comment: The demarcation is that Javascript is the actual Turing-Complete Programming Language in use.  Graphics can be manipulated by Javascript using Canvas or a number of other techniques, so the line you're trying to draw is not that sharp.

Comment: So in HTML5 apps, Javascript will always be the turing-complete language in use? Or is it also possible to use e.g. PHP?

Comment: PHP is generally thought-of as a server-side language. You might use it to generate an HTML5 template, and inject content into it using Javascript, etc. Javascript is client-side when associated with the browser, although it can be run server side, i.e. Node.JS

Comment: Okay, so generally when somebody says "HTML5 app", they mean: an application that runs inside the browser, and uses HTML5 and CSS3 for the UI, and Javascript for the functionality. Yes?

Comment: Pretty much. Usually there's also some sort of backend technology that communicates with the HTML5 app.

Comment: So pretty much the difference between an HTML5 app and an 'old' client-side app is the newer HTML and CSS versions?

Comment: I'd say that's fair, since, y'know, there's a 5 in HTML5.  Although HTML wasn't really seriously considered for mobile apps prior to HTML5.

Comment: This is somewhat nitpicking, but people also often mean "browser features not actually part of the HTML5 spec per se, but part of some other standard developed at roughly the same time as HTML5".  For example, WebGL isn't part of the W3C HTML5 spec.  Most people don't need to care about the difference.  Most people saying "HTML5 application" are unaware such distinctions are possible to make.

Comment: Do HTML5 apps always run in a browser? Or are there common interpreters for HTML5/JS/CSS installed on the device itself? E.g. if you run an HTML5 app in an Android phone does that mean you run it in the phone's browser?

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html